# How do i get the launch intent for my work profile app from my app in the primary profile?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-enterprise

This question targets Android for work.

I have written an app including a DevicePolicyController following this [guide](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/build-dpc.html). The controller creates a managed profile for my Android device.

I added an app to that profile which is called **FooApp**.
Now I can see two icons of **FooApp** in my launcher, one with work badge and one without.

I also have an app **BarApp**, which is only in the primary profile.
How do I get the launch intent for the work version of **FooApp** in **BarApp**? (Start the work version of **FooApp** from within **BarApp**)

I can't use [CrossProfileApps](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/CrossProfileApps) as I am on API 23.

Comment: What do you mean by "the work version of FooApp"? What is the difference between the 2 versions of the app?

Comment: The work version has got a different UID and data scope. See: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/managed-profiles#settings

Comment: I just managed to launch the work version by adding an custom intent and intent filter to **FooApp** and adding a crossprofileintentfilter for that very intent to my devicepolicycontroller. Then i fire the intent from **BarApp**. The user can now decide on his own to use the work version. But using the work version by default would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution I came up with cannot happen without the users consent. Maybe there will be a better one in the future. But here is mine:

I added the following intent filter for FooActivity in the Manifest of **FooApp**.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.example.FooApp.ACTION_HOMELAUNCHER"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Then I added a crossProfileIntentfilter for my work profile (put the following code in the profile administration app currently running in the work profile).

```
DevicePolicyManager manager =
            (DevicePolicyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
ComponentName componentName = BasicDeviceAdminReceiver.getComponentName(context);
IntentFilter filterin = new IntentFilter("com.example.FooApp.ACTION_HOMELAUNCHER");
manager.addCrossProfileIntentFilter(componentName, filterin, DevicePolicyManager.FLAG_MANAGED_CAN_ACCESS_PARENT);
```

In the end, when I want to launch the App in the work profile, I fire the `ACTION_HOMELAUNCHER` intent from **BarApp** and then the user can select, whether he wants to lauch the work profile version or the normal version of **FooApp**.

Feel free to improve upon this answer.